# Access a Lambda API from the private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to access a Lambda API from the private subnet?

I see that there are VPC endpoints to handle AWS services accessibility from the private subnet, however, there is no support for the Lambda API.

Is there any other way to use Lambda API without having internet access?

Comment: Can you provide a little information about what you are trying to do?  For example, are you trying to trigger a lambda from an EC2 instance's AWS CLI?

Comment: we're trying to create a Lambda function using AWS SDK from EC2 instance placed in the private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no VPC endpoint available for Lambda which can be used to hit the Lambda API without routing your request over the internet.

If you don't want to give internet access to your service making the Lambda call, you can use a [Private API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) which integrates with the Lambda function/service as the back-end. The private API gateway endpoint can be invoked using the `execute-api` VPC endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html